# How to digitized a sketch and to get soft lines?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, vector, digital

To color in Photoshop my traditional sketches, I start by digitizing my drawing in [autotracer.org](https://www.autotracer.org/), and I get a vector graphics as this one:

[image]

I like it, but I'd like to know if there's a way I can make the lines “less heavy” and to get a crayon texture.

(I don't have a drawing tablet, then I can't do it by simply lining it with a soft brush).

Edit (30-01-2021): Full picture of my scanned drawing is showed below.
[image]

Comment: What application are you using.

Comment: @joojaa Do you mean the application I use for coloring? Firealpaca

Comment: It would be helpful to see the raw scan as well. Preferably in 100% size. Could just be a small part of it. I wouldn't necessarily convert the drawing to vector. If it's relatively clean, I think you get a more organic result by cleaning up the drawing as a raster image and color it as such.

Comment: @Wolff I'll try what you suggest, thank you !

Comment: Can you share part of the original scan please? What your showing here is only the result of your efforts so far, which kind of limits the possible answers here. Thanks.

Comment: @Billy Kerr sorry for the late reply ! I'll edit right now my post with the scanned picture.

Comment: Use a proper vector image editor to create the trace.  Software such as Illustrator or Inkscape (which is free) has a threshold control you can adjust when you trace it. Reducing the threshold will give you thinner lines.

Comment: Your scanned image shows how your drawing is actually nice and clean to begin with. I feel like posting an answer showing how I would edit this without turning it into vector. But it would be nice to have a crop showing the scan at *100% scale*. The posted image must be zoomed out right? (if not it should be scanned at higher resolution.) When working with the quality of the lines in an image, it's much about details at the pixel level.

Comment: @Billy Kerr I'll give a try to Inkscape, thank you so much !

Comment: @Wolff I'll be sharing the full scanned image then ! It's not zoomed though, maybe I need to increase the resolution when scanning.  Thank you in advance for offering your help !

Comment: OK, I don't think I have an answer much different from the given then. Only I would use the scan instead of the vectorized version and add the noise in a bit different way. But honestly I like the lines as they are in the scan. Not "soft" as such, but not as hard as in the vectorized version. The resolution is a bit low. For screen it's OK I guess, but if you want to print it you'll probably need higher resolution. Depends on how big you want it of course. Should print at about 300 ppi and maybe be scanned at 600 ppi to make editing easier and get a sharper result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your traced image has no lines, it's a complex compound path. The drawn lines are now (with black) filled areas, there's no vector strokes that could be changed (see NOTE1).

The consequence: Filled areas have no direction. No ordinary image editing program can decide how your hand had moved. The only way to recreate realistic manually drawn looking brush, pencil or crayon strokes is to draw them, but you already said that it's not possible because you do not have any computer hardware which obeys your hand.

If you can accept only changing the black color to some noisy texture you can proceed in Photoshop, Krita, GIMP or other program which has ability to insert noise and layer masks. An example:

[image]

I don't have your traced image, but I increased the pixel dimensions of your screenshot to 400% with Smilla Enlargener and added contrast to get somehow sharp version of your image.

Smilla guesses sharp edges quite succesfully, so it doesn't increase blurriness nor jagginess like usual image scaling methods do.

The scanned image with enough contrast would, of course be better for this route, tracing is here useless. This is made in Photoshop:

The image was inverted and used as layer mask. The layer has solid 50% grey fill which has got Filter > Noise > Add Noise > Monochrome

Layer mask refinement can be used to contract the width of the apparent lines:

[image]

The image I originally copied from your post was noisy, so increasing layer mask contrast pulls it up. It's applied here. To keep the image contrast good the layer fill is black and there's less noise. The mask refinement is used with maximum mask contrast and edges are shifted:

[image]

Colorizing your image is not possible with paint bucket due the sparse line pattern, but I guess you are going to paint with brushes into a layer below the BW lines and make manual area selections for sharp color edges In that case it can be useful to use layer blending mode = Multiply for the lines layer because the color shines through the white areas between the black particles. Another way is to have all noise in the layer mask.

BTW. You seemingly have something that many of us only dream - real drawing tools obey your will. Consider to print a copy of your drawing with thinned lines and paint on it manually with real colors.

**NOTE1**: Ability to trace drawn curves as curves, not as filled areas has been in the wish list as long as tracing has existed. The results have been mostly poor, they usually fail in line crossings and. Programs which trace only technical drawings succeed better because they assume certain radically limited collection of possible line types and curvatures  - maybe only straight or circular lines. But you can try tracing in Inkscape. It has midline tracing - only the usual "lose ones way in the crossings"  but at least it exists.

Comment: Excellent your answers :-)

Comment: This is exactly the effect I was looking for, thank you so much for your detailed answer !